# How to pass xml input (request) to Web api on .net core 3.1

Tags: xml, asp.net-core, fiddler, webapi

I have a .net core 3.1 web api. I have tried the following but it always turns up null when it hits it

```
[HttpPost]     
    public IActionResult ReturnXmlDocument(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result);        
        return Ok(doc.DocumentElement.OuterXml.ToString());
    }
```

It doent even hits it during debugging also it shows a 415 error in fiddler.

Comment: I have tried passing content type and accept headers as XML to no avail

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Asp.net core no longer uses HttpRequestMessage or HttpResponseMessage.

So, if you want to accept a xml format request, you should do the below steps:

1.Install the **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml** NuGet package.

2.Call **AddXmlSerializerFormatters** In Startup.ConfigureServices.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers()
            .AddXmlSerializerFormatters(); 
    }
```

3.Apply the **Consumes** attribute to controller classes or action methods that should expect XML in the request body.

```
 [HttpPost]
    [Consumes("application/xml")]
    public IActionResult Post(Model model)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
```

For more details, you can refer to the offical document of [Model binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#input-formatters)

Comment: Your solution works..thnaks....i want to know addtionally i do not want to declare a model OR when i want to save the input in string or in XMLDocument directly. will it be possible

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I noticed that it works even without [Consumes("application/xml")] attribute.

Comment: Caution doesn't use services.AddControllers().AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters(), use only services.AddControllers().AddXmlSerializerFormatters()

Answer (score 1):

**For newer versions of .NET Core**

The previous answer from [mj1313](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11965297/mj1313) was correct, but the "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml" library is now deprecated and no longer maintained.

I found a more simple and still valid solution for .NET Core MVC apis, just add this ".AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters()" method call to your Program.cs file:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddControllers().AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters();
}
```

Source: https://gavilan.blog/2020/01/22/asp-net-core-3-1-accept-and-content-type-adding-xml-support-to-a-web-api/